# Determine next script to execute, while interpreter is working

Tags: python, windows, interpreter

I am going to explain my problem by example:

I've got a python script `A.py` which takes a long time to execute. During this time I decide to execute `B.py` after `A.py` is completed. But I rather want to do something other than sitting and watching for when I can start `B.py`.

Is there a way to shedule `B.py` while `A.py` is running? 
Is it possible to write a `.bat` (or something else) which waits until `A.py` is completed and starts `B.py`?

EDIT: I am working with windows.

Maybe there is a flag like "interpreter_is_busy"?

Comment: windows or *nix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your questions is that you are trying to run two separate Python processes: one running script `A.py`, and the other one running `B.py` right after the first one finishes.

If my assumption is correct, you can write a batch (`.bat`) file to run the processes, one after the other. Since the second one will not get executed before the first one finishes, you should get what you expect.

```
python A.py
python B.py
```

I have a feeling you are trying to do something more complicated, though, so correct me in the comments if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does what I asked for, since I can modify `B.py` while `A.py` is running. Actually quite a simple solution. Thank you.